# Ghost: invalid ghost-cli version error message when restarting

Tags: ghost-blog

I have problems restarting ghost after updating to ghost 3.0. When I run the command ‘ghost version’ in the htdocs folder I get:

> Ghost-CLI version: 1.13.1 Ghost version: 3.0.3 (at
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs)

But when I run ‘ghost start’ or similar commands I get the following message:

> Ghost-CLI only works with Ghost versions >= 1.0.0. If you are trying
>   to upgrade Ghost LTS to 1.0.0, refer to
>   https://ghost.org/faq/upgrade-to-ghost-1-0/. Otherwise, run `ghost
>   start` again within a valid Ghost installation.

Did anybody have the same issue or maybe know a fix?